# Create model class in Scala with Play 2 Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play project, who contains a User model. Before, I used `case class` declaration with `object` declaration to access the model in my application. It works.

But now I want to declare a User class, to have multiple instances ; because I have understand that when you have a model with an object, it'as a singleton, so one instance.

And my project is a website which will have many users.

When I declare my class, as example :

```
class User(val username: String,  var firstname: String, var lastname: String, var company: String, var password: String){}
```

The model isn't identified by my application (Application.scala)

How can I realise what I want ?

Old code :

```
case class User(username: String, password: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, company: String)

object User {

val simple = {
  get[String]("username")  ~
  get[String]("password") ~
  get[String]("firstname") ~
  get[String]("lastname")  ~
  get[String]("company") map {
    case username~password~firstname~lastname~company =>
      User(username, password, firstname, lastname, company)
  }
}

def findAll(): Seq[User] = {
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL("SELECT * FROM user").as(User.simple *)
  }
}

def create(user: User): Unit = {
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL("INSERT INTO user(username, password, firstname, lastname, company) VALUES   ({username}, {password}, {firstname}, {lastname}, {company})").on(
      'username  -> user.username,
      'password  -> user.password,
      'firstname -> user.firstname,
      'lastname  -> user.lastname,
      'company   -> user.company
    ).executeUpdate()
  }
}

def getOne(username: String): Option[User] = {
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    val selectUser = SQL("SELECT username, password, firstname, lastname, company FROM user where username={username}")
                      .on('username -> "azuken")()
                      .collectFirst {
                        case Row(username: String, password: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, company: String) =>
                          User(username, password, firstname, lastname, company)
                        case Row(username:String, password:String, firstname: String) =>
                          User(username, password, "bobby", "lqsdast", "sdf")
                        case _ =>
                          User("username", "password", "firstname", "lastname", "company")
                      }
    selectUser
  }
} 

def authentication(username: String, password: String): Long = {
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    val firstRow = SQL("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NbRep FROM user WHERE username = {username} AND password = {password}").on(
      'username -> username,
      'password -> password
    ).apply().head
    firstRow[Long]("NbRep")
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Your 'old code' looks fine. What is the problem? You have a class (or case class) `User` and a companion object named `User`. No problems there.

Comment: Yes, i know, but with this code, I can't have multiple instance, right ? The fact to have an object in the model makes a Singleton ?

Comment: You could: `val user1 = User(...); val user2 = User(...)`. You could even use the `new` keyword: `val user3 = new User(...)`

Comment: It works with this "old" code, but with only a `class User() {}` the controller doesn't see the model

Comment: Seems like you're still hung up on the companion object. [This article](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/companion-object.html) may help you understand.

Comment: Okay, so with a companion object you can access to a class without instanciate. But this is not what I want, because, if some users want to access, they can't do it at the same time ?

Comment: Could you put your project on GitHub and point out the problem?